# How can I recover parent after I made parent repo private and then public again?

Tags: github

Apologize if it's not the right place.

I created a public repo in github for my team and all the team members forked the repo into their own account.

For some reason **I made the parent repo in my account private**. Unfortunately one of the repo in team member's accounts is chosen as a new parent. They cannot send pull requests to my repo now. It doesn't work even if I added all of them as collaborators. After some search, my repo and the forks are now in separated network.

Now I'm going to **make the repo in my account public again**. Will my repo be the parent again automatically?  I don't think so. It looks like the repos in team member's accounts are in a separate network now.

So the question is, how can I make my repo the parent again? So that other guys can send pull requests to repo in my account other than the new parent. Because there are significant changes in one of forks, it's better he doesn't need to fork again.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell everyone to delete their forks and then re-fork off your repo when you get it in the state you want.

You can cherry-pick the commits from their fork before they delete theirs, or alternatively they can re-push their commits from their local branch after they create a new fork.